# jQuery toggleClass doesn't work properly on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I'm having a trouble with jQuery toggle function, which work great on PC, but doesn't work on mobile devices.

I have mobile navigation with image icon as an opening link. On click, it should change class to active, which changes its background image from classic menu bar to cross. Someone with the same issue and know how to solve it?

Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#toggle-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
});



#toggle-menu {
width: 30px; height: 30px; display: block;
background: url('menu-bar.png') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;
}


.active#toggle-menu {
background: url('menu-cross.png') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: @Satpal it still doesn't work. actually - it does, but not properly.. I have to click like 3-5 times to change img to "menu-cross" and than again 3-5 times to change it back to "menu-bar"
but I will change the code here

Comment: Sounds like it got partially _hidden_ behind another element and just when clicked on that exact _visible_ part it responds

Comment: @LGSon but on PC it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling an "active" class to the id toggle-menu so your compound class is incorrect. It needs to be this for you to select and style it:

```
    #toggle-menu.active {
    background: url('menu-cross.png') no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```